# How to print superscript in Python

Tags: python, sympy

I'm aware of the sympy module in python and I know how to use it most of the time, however, I need to append different values to a list and then join it into a string. I need to append the superscript 'x' at the end of the list. Here's my code:

```
from functions import *
from subprocess import run
from sympy import pretty_print as pp
from sympy.abc import x

try:
    run("clear", shell=True)

    print("\033[92m[*] Initializing Exponential Equation Calculator", end='', flush=True)
    print_dots(3)

    while True:
        print("\n\n================================Select Option================================")
        print("1. Create exponential equation\n2. Calculate exponential growth\n3. Calculate exponential decay\n4. Exit")

        try:
            option = int(input(">>> "))
        except ValueError:
            handle_error("Please enter an option from above")
            continue

        if option == 1:
            equation = ["y = "]
            while True:
                points_table = get_points()
                for j in points_table:
                    i = 0
                    status = 0
                    while i < len(j):
                        if j[i] == 0:
                            yInt = j[i + 1]
                            status += 1
                            break
                        i += 1
                    if status == 1:
                        break

                growth_rate = find_pattern(points_table)

                if growth_rate is None:
                    handle_error("There is no exponential pattern in the table provided. Try again", 1)
                    continue

                equation.append(str(yInt))
                equation.append(" * ")
                equation.append(str(growth_rate))
                result = ''.join(equation)

                print(f"\033[93m[*] Equation Calculated! The equation is \033[96m{result}\033[92m")
                sleep(2)
                while True:
                    try:
                        print("================================Select Option================================")
                        print("Would you like to:\n\n1. Calculate another equation\n2. Choose a different option\n3. Exit")
                        choice = int(input(">>> "))

                        if choice == 1 or choice == 2:
                            break

                        elif choice == 3:
                            raise KeyboardInterrupt

                        else:
                            handle_error("Please enter a valid option")
                            continue

                    except ValueError:
                        handle_error("Please enter a valid option")
                        continue

                if choice == 2:
                    break

        elif option == 2:
            pass

        elif option == 3:
            pass

        elif option == 4:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt

        else:
            handle_error("Please enter an option from above")
            continue
        break

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n\033[96m[*] Shutting down...\n\033[0m")
    exit(0)
```

In the lines where there's 3 append functions, I don't know how I'm supposed to add the superscript 'x' to the end of the list. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The usual methods are to use either "**" or "^".

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts but i want to actually put a small 'x' on the top right of a number. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Not in the console.  You are limited to the characters that the console font supports.  Some clever beasts do that in two lines: you write out one line with the exponents in the right spot, then a second line with the rest of the equation.  It's a bitch to get them to line up.